# Nvidia or Intel graphics cause crash when high load usage

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, crash, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

The following software crashes when I use default graphic settings:

- After Effects 2019
- Photoshop 2019
- Unreal Engine 4
- Android Studio device emulators

I had to change the graphics settings on some of these products in order to work properly, but slower.

Is there any way to use my graphic card?

Asus GL553VD Config:

- Windows 10 1903 with latest updates
- i7 7700HQ (Intel 630 HD) (undervolted)
- NVIDIA GTX 1050 4gb (not overclocked)
- NVIDIA driver 431.60
- Intel driver 26.20.100.6912

I searched a lot about this issue, maybe compatibility problem, or the Nvidia and Intel versions having problems?

Comment: I don't think it's a compatibility issue since it's a laptop. With that said, what did you try so far? Your question gives so little information that anyone couldn't answer it. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1467617/edit) the question to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Intel® HD Graphics 630 Display Adaptor via Device Manager and see if that makes a difference.

Have you tried removing and reinstalling graphics drivers? It might be worth using Display Driver Uninstaller (DDU). There is a guide here: https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/ddu-guide-tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm always using DDU when i install new driver, it not solve the problem, i will try disabling the intel driver and let you know the results

Comment: Still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Of those, at least Photoshop uses OpenGL & is known to be 'not friendly' at sharing the OGL memory.
Prefs/Performance. Disable the Use Graphics Processor switch [or open advanced & set to minimum.] Relaunch.

See if the same can be done for After Effects [which I don't use so can't test.]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a graphics card issue. Stress test the components individually to ascertain which is causing the problem. To test CPU use Prine95, for RAM use Memtest86, for graphics use FurMark or OCCT. There are many others to use. You find out more information about stress testing on tomshardware.com.

Comment: Stress test goes OK for gpu, cpu and ram